# How to improve GUI by changing BoxLayout into a different LayoutManager?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, boxlayout

I've a big problem with Swing in Java, I used BoxLayout for this but still it looks bad.
Any suggestions about my usage of layouts, or how to change it to look like in assumptions? ([here are assumptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcCzA.jpg))

```
Container main = new Container();
    Container left = new Container();// here goin buttons
    Container right = new Container(); // here goin tabs +  more buttons, textfields and other stuff

    BoxLayout lewyL = new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    left.setLayout(lewyL);
    left.add(rastrowa); //radiobutton
    left.add(wektorowa);//radiobutton
    left.add(apDwuliniowa);//checkbox
    left.add(wczytaj);//button
    left.add(zapisz);//obutton
    left.add(wyczysc);//button
    BoxLayout prawyL = new BoxLayout(right, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    right.setLayout(prawyL);
    right.add(zakladki);// tabs (mostly i use BoxLayout but for last one i need something more "complicated")
```

EDIT: I almost solve this problem, I need to move all elements to left ([how it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfxR5.png))but I have no idea how ;/ Here is constructor of this class.

```
            JLabel label = new JLabel("O wektor");
    JLabel labelA = new JLabel("a:");
    JLabel labelB = new JLabel("b:");
    JButton wykonaj = new JButton("Wykonaj");
    JTextField a = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField b = new JTextField(5);
    add(label);
    add(labelA);
    add(a);
    add(labelB);
    add(b);
    add(wykonaj);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the way it looks (in my opinion), but if you want it to look a little better, why don't you convert the left panel (which is 6x1) into a 3x2 panel, with the checkboxes/radiobuttons on the left, and buttons on the right? Sounds like a job for `GridLayout` - one of my favorite classes...

```
JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
leftPanel.add(rastrowa);     //radiobutton
leftPanel.add(wczytaj);      //button
leftPanel.add(wektorowa);    //radiobutton
leftPanel.add(zapisz);       //obutton
leftPanel.add(apDwuliniowa); //checkbox
leftPanel.add(wyczysc);      //button
```

Note that the `3,2` defines the number of rows,columns. When adding panels, they are added to the grid from left-to-right, and top-to-bottom. `GridLayout` also auto-sizes the components, so all the buttons etc will be the same width and height, making it look more consistent.

The [GridLayout documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) might be useful, and the [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a great place to see other layout managers that might work better for your different situations. I personally find `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout` to be the most useful, and cover about 95% of the situations I ever need for my GUIs.

Comment: I tried with GridLayout, i still need help how to do interface whats fit in program size(setBounds(950,650))